# (Python 3) I have some questions regarding seek() and tell()

Tags: python, file, seek, tell

I am currently learning Python 3 with the Zed Shaw's book, Learning Python 3 The Hard Way.

When doing exercise 20 about functions and files, you get tasked with researcher what does the **seek function** does. By searching online I've come across with a couple of concepts regarding this function that I'm having trouble getting my head around:

Here's an explanation I've found online about **seek()**'s purpose:

> Python file method seek() sets the file's current position at the offset.

- Under this context, what would "The file's current position" mean?

Here's an explanation I've found online about **tell()**'s purpose:

> Python file method tell() returns the current position of the file read/write pointer within the file.

- Under this context, what would "The file read/write pointer" mean?

Comment: Both mean the same. They refere to a position in the file from where reading and writing will be done. Similar to the position of the magnetic head of a cassette recorder.

Comment: FYI: https://sopython.com/wiki/LPTHW_Complaints

Answer (score 2):

You can think of a file as a sequence of bytes (at least that is the case if you open up the file as a binary file using `mode='rb'`), similar to a `bytearray` stored on disk. When you first open the file with `mode='rb'`, you are currently positioned or "pointing" at the beginning of the file, at offset 0, meaning that if you issue a `read` for `n` bytes you will be reading in the *first* `n` bytes of the file (assuming the file has at least `n` bytes worth of data). After the read your new file position is at offset `n`. So if you do nothing but issue successive `read` calls, you will read the file sequentially.

Method `tell` returns your current "position", meaning simply your current offset within the file:

```
with open('myfile', 'rb') as f:
    data = f.read(12) # after this read I should be at offset 12
    print(f.tell()) # this should print out 12
```

Method `seek` allows you to change your current position in the file:

```
import os

with open('myfile', 'rb') as f:
    # read the last 12 bytes of the file:
    f.seek(-12, os.SEEK_END) # seek 12 bytes before the end of the file
    data = f.read(12) # after this read I should be at the end of the file
```